# Парсинг html

Tags: парсер, ios, xcode, objective-c, iphone

Всё, что нашел толкового в гугле, это:

```
 NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:
 @"http://hashcode.ru/"];

 NSURLRequest *urlRequest =
 [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
 urlString cachePolicy:
 NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
 timeoutInterval: 10];
 
 NSURLResponse *response = nil;
 
 NSError *error = nil;
 
 NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection
 sendSynchronousRequest :urlRequest
 returningResponse :&response error
 :&error];
 
 NSString *result= [[NSString alloc]
 initWithData :urlData encoding:
 NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Как я понял, это получение самого кода... но мне нужно вытянуть дату, например "`<dat>19.12.2013</dat>`", парсинг от `<dat>` и до `<` вставить в `label`.
Подскажите кодика ^^ :***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [гитхабе](https://github.com) есть масса парсеров:

- [Раз](https://github.com/Objective3/ElementParser)
- [Два](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)
- [Три](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple)

Comment: Вы просите парсер для HTML, я дал вам ссылки. 

Что конкретно вам непонятно?

Задавайте вопросы.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что спрашивающий не совсем понимает, что ему в конечном счёте нужно )))

Comment: @AlexDenisov, а не подскажете парсер с использованием Core Foundation или на С/C++? Gumbo не предлагать, тяжёлый.

Answer (score 1):

Я подозреваю, что самый простой способ это воспользоваться библиотекой [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), которая из коробки делает HTTP-запросы и разбирает HTTP-ответы: смотрите на странице проекта примеры, например, AFXMLRequestOperation или AFJSONRequestOperation.

Даже и помимо решения вопросов с парсингом я бы советовал вам начать использовать AFNetworking, так как это самая уже-очень-давно и всеми-всеми используемая библиотека для работы с сетью: HTTP, запросами-ответами, JSON, XML, ...

Comment: Еще такая есть

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Comment: Я думаю для спрашивающего это будет уж слишком круто.

Comment: Я отвечаю исходя из того, что вижу sendSynchronousRequest в вопросе и это сразу же настораживает.